# How to COUNT total wall posts of Facebook Fan Page (Public Profile) which is not mine in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to store some stats about fan pages (like count, shares, etc) but cant understand how to count Page's total wall posts? Preferably want to use FQL but any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 1):

here is code to (like count, shares, etc)

```
$source_url = "http://www.flightpodcast.com/episode-6-john-bartels-qantas-qf30";
$url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode($source_url);
$xml = file_get_contents($url);//echo "<pre/>";print_r($xml);exit;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo "<b>Shares:</b> ".$shares = $xml->link_stat->share_count;echo "<br/>";
echo "<b>Likes:</b> ".$likes = $xml->link_stat->like_count;echo "<br/>";
echo "<b>Comments:</b> ".$comments = $xml->link_stat->comment_count;echo "<br/>";
echo "<b>Total:</b> ".$total = $xml->link_stat->total_count;echo "<br/>";
```

Comment: thank you for support, but I need to count Wall Posts, likes and shares already implemented via FQL

Answer (score 1):

Run a FQL query against the [link_stat](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) table:

FQL:
    SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://example.com"

PHP:
$facebook->api_client->fql_query('SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://example.com"');

This FQL query might require now an access token - so try adding that if the above fail.

You can also access the graph api: http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://example.com.

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I need Wallposts count and nothibg else ))

Answer (score 0):

FQL has no COUNT function in their API, so you would have to get all the posts and count them yourself.

You can use something like PHP to do this in the following manner:

```
    $fqlAPIParams = array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => '
                SELECT  post_id
                FROM    stream
                WHERE   actor_id = '.$pageId.' AND
                        source_id = '.$pageId.' 
                        LIMIT 999999'
    );
    $result = $facebook->api($fqlAPIParams);
    $postCount = 0;
    foreach( $result as $post ) {
         $postCount++;
    }
```

Hope that can still help someone, as the question is pretty old.